# Sinatra app won't publish to Heroku

Tags: heroku, sinatra

I have a very simple Sinatra app that I'm trying to publish to Heroku. I've got the accounts created, and the app runs fine locally, but when I type:

```
git push heroku master (from within the applications root folder)
```

I get:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
!     Heroku push rejected, no Rails or Rack app detected

To git@heroku.com:pure-mist-880.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:pure-mist-880.git'
```

My config.ru file is super simple (and possibly the problem, as I've seen a couple of different ways to write one...):

```
require './raffle'

map '/' do
run Raffler
end
```

But it all runs fine locally.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple is good. I got a Sinatra application working on Heroku with this `config.ru` file:

```
require './app'
run App
```

The `app.rb` contains something like this (its a modular style app):

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your inspiration. I started from scratch with an app like yours and realized Heroku was complaining because it couldn't find 'sinatra/base'. I did some looking around and found that Heroku wants a .gems manifest listing all the gems required by your app. I wrote up one of those for my main app, and everything is better (minus my CSS... that isn't loading). Thanks again!

Comment: Instead of just using a .gems file, you should use Bundler (http://gembundler.com/).